# How do I hook in to after_validation_on_update callback in a Rails 3 observer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, callback, observer-pattern

I want to hook in to the `after_validation` event only for an update action, using an observer in Rails 3.2. In Rails 2, I could define:

```
def after_validation_on_update(model)
  ...
end
```

inside the observer, but this method is no longer in the callbacks in favour of the new `after_validation(:on => create)` method. How can I do this in Rails 3.2?

Comment: It looks like `after_validation_on_update` was depricated. You can try `after_validation, :on => :update` to see if that works.

Comment: Thanks for the note. Yeah. I saw that it was deprecated. The macro-style hook doesn't work in observers though, as far as I can tell.